# Linker errors running bjam on Boost Python Tutorial

Tags: boost, boost-python, lnk2019, bjam, lnk2001

I have been working on solving this problem for fourty hours now, using every boost python resource I could find, and every permutation of installation and building I can think of, but could not find anything that worked for me.

Like many people before me, I am getting linker errors when I run bjam inside the `boost/boost_1_60_0/libs/python/example/tutorial` directory. I have Visual Studio 2015, and I have tried running bjam with 32-bit Anaconda, 64-bit Anaconda, and plain Python 2.7, through different configurations of the `user-config.jam` file located in my home directory.

Here is the build log after running `bjam` with any settings.

```
    Performing configuration checks

        - 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
        - arm                      : no  (cached)
        - mips1                    : no  (cached)
        - power                    : no  (cached)
        - sparc                    : no  (cached)
        - x86                      : yes (cached)
    ...found 7 targets...
        - symlinks supported       : yes
    ...found 1 target...
    ...updating 1 target...
    config-cache.write bin\project-cache.jam
    ...updated 1 target...
    ...patience...
    ...patience...
    ...found 1917 targets...
    ...updating 9 targets...
    msvc.link.dll ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll
       Creating library ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib and object ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.exp
    object_protocol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
    wrapper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
    numeric.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
    enum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
    function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
    numeric.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCallable_Check referenced in function "bool __cdecl boost::python::numeric::`anonymous namespace'::load(bool)" (?load@?A0xc5ed2080@numeric@python@boost@@YA_N_N@Z)
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCallable_Check
    function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
    function_doc_signature.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
    numeric.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
    list.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
    enum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_FromLong
    numeric.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyBool_FromLong referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::python::converter::arg_to_python<bool>::arg_to_python<bool>(bool const &)" (??0?$arg_to_python@_N@converter@python@boost@@QAE@AB_N@Z)
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyBool_FromLong
    numeric.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::python::converter::arg_to_python<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::arg_to_python<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$arg_to_python@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@converter@python@boost@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
    str.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize
    builtin_converters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize
    function_doc_signature.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize
    numeric.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Clear referenced in function "bool __cdecl boost::python::numeric::`anonymous namespace'::load(bool)" (?load@?A0xc5ed2080@numeric@python@boost@@YA_N_N@Z)
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Clear
    function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Clear
    object_protocol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Clear
    function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Format
    numeric.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Format
    from_python.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Format
    registry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Format
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Format
    enum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    pickle_support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    stl_iterator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    numeric.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    list.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    dict.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    str.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_CallFunction
    numeric.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyImport_Import referenced in function "bool __cdecl boost::python::numeric::`anonymous namespace'::load(bool)" (?load@?A0xc5ed2080@numeric@python@boost@@YA_N_N@Z)
    numeric.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_IsInstance referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl boost::python::numeric::aux::array_object_manager_traits::check(struct _object *)" (?check@array_object_manager_traits@aux@numeric@python@boost@@SA_NPAU_object@@@Z)
    from_python.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_IsInstance
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_IsInstance
    wrapper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    import.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    exec.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    function_doc_signature.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    iterator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    stl_iterator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    object_protocol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    life_support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    pickle_support.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    builtin_converters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    registry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    enum.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    tuple.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    str.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    slice.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    from_python.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    numeric.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    list.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    long.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    dict.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
    numeric.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_ImportError
    list.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_AsLong referenced in function "public: int __thiscall boost::python::detail::list_base::count(class boost::python::api::object const &)const " (?count@list_base@detail@python@boost@@QBEHABVobject@api@34@@Z)
    str.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_AsLong
    class.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_AsLong
    builtin_converters.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyInt_AsLong
    list.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_New referenced in function "protected: __thiscall boost::python::detail::list_base::list_base(void)" (??0list_base@detail@python@boost@@IAE@XZ)
    list.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_Insert referenced in function "public: void __thiscall boost::python::detail::list_base::insert(int,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (?insert@list_base@detail@python@boost@@QAEXHABVobject@api@34@@Z)
    list.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyList_Append referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
....
....(too many to put here)
....
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Add referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator+(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Hapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Subtract referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator-(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Gapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Multiply referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator*(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Dapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Divide referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator/(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Kapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Remainder referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator%(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Lapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Lshift referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator<<(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??6api@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Rshift referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator>>(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??5api@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_And referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator&(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Iapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Xor referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator^(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Tapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_Or referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::api::operator|(class boost::python::api::object const &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Uapi@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@012@ABV3012@0@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceAdd referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator+=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Yapi@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceSubtract referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator-=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Zapi@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceMultiply referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator*=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??Xapi@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceDivide referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator/=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_0api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceRemainder referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator%=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_1api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceLshift referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator<<=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_3api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceRshift referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator>>=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_2api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceAnd referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator&=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_4api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceXor referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator^=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_6api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    object_operators.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyNumber_InPlaceOr referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object & __cdecl boost::python::api::operator|=(class boost::python::api::object &,class boost::python::api::object const &)" (??_5api@python@boost@@YAAAVobject@012@AAV3012@ABV3012@@Z)
    wrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_GetItemString referenced in function "protected: class boost::python::override __thiscall boost::python::detail::wrapper_base::get_override(char const *,struct _typeobject *)const " (?get_override@wrapper_base@detail@python@boost@@IBE?AVoverride@34@PBDPAU_typeobject@@@Z)
    wrapper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyMethod_Type
    import.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyImport_ImportModule referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::import(class boost::python::str)" (?import@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@@Z)
    exec.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFile_FromString referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::exec_file(class boost::python::str,class boost::python::api::object,class boost::python::api::object)" (?exec_file@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@V3412@1@Z)
    exec.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFile_AsFile referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::exec_file(class boost::python::str,class boost::python::api::object,class boost::python::api::object)" (?exec_file@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@V3412@1@Z)
    exec.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyRun_StringFlags referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::eval(class boost::python::str,class boost::python::api::object,class boost::python::api::object)" (?eval@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@V3412@1@Z)
    exec.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyRun_FileExFlags referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::exec_file(class boost::python::str,class boost::python::api::object,class boost::python::api::object)" (?exec_file@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@V3412@1@Z)
    exec.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyEval_GetGlobals referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::eval(class boost::python::str,class boost::python::api::object,class boost::python::api::object)" (?eval@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@V3412@1@Z)
    C:\Users\Joey\Anaconda2\libs\python27.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
    ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 135 unresolved externals

            call "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd" >nul
    link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll" /IMPLIB:"..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Joey\Anaconda2\libs"   @"..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll.rsp"
            if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

    ...failed msvc.link.dll ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.pdb...
    ...removing ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib
    ...removing ..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.pdb
    ...skipped <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello_ext.dll for lack of <p..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib...
    ...skipped <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello_ext.pdb for lack of <p..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib...
    ...skipped <p.>boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll for lack of <p..\..\..\..\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll...
    ...skipped <p.>hello_ext.dll for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello_ext.dll...
    ...skipped <pbin\hello.test\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello_ext.dll...
    ...failed updating 3 targets...
    ...skipped 6 targets...
```

I have tried numerous user-config.jam settings, including each of the following for msvc:

```
using msvc : 14.0 ;
using msvc : 14.0 : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin" ;
using msvc ;
```

as well as the following for python:

```
using python ;
using python : 2.7 ;
using python : 2.7 : C:/Users/Joey/Anaconda2 ;

using python : 2.7 : "C:/Users/Joey/Anaconda2 (32-bit)" ;

using python 
    : 2.7                   # Version
    : C:\\Users\\Joey\\Anaconda2\\python.exe      # Python Path
    : C:\\Users\\Joey\\Anaconda2\\include         # include path
    : C:\\Users\\Joey\\Anaconda2\\libs            # lib path(s)
    : <define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
    ;
```

for bjam settings, I have tried

```
bjam
bjam address-model=64
bjam address-model=64 architecture=x86
```

I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit builds of the entire Boost library, with identical results.

When I run `bjam address-model=64`, I get the following errors much more quickly:

```
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
    - symlinks supported       : no  (cached)
    - junctions supported      : yes (cached)
    - hardlinks supported      : yes (cached)
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
config-cache.write bin\project-cache.jam
...updated 1 target...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1924 targets...
...updating 5 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd
   Creating library bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb and object bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.exp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb'

        call "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_amd64.cmd" >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /NOENTRY /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd" /IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Joey\Anaconda2\libs"   @"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd.rsp"
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb...
...removing bin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pyd for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi>hello_ext.pyd...
...skipped <pbin\hello.test\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi>hello for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threading-multi>hello_ext.pyd...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 3 targets...
```

I am running Windows 10 64-bit.

If anyone has any intuition into things to try, the nature of the problem, or anything else that could be helpful, I would greatly appreciate it. I am nearly running out of ideas.

**EDIT**

I used

```
    import toolset : using ;
using msvc : 14.0 ;
using python 
  : 2.7  # Version
  : C:\\Python27\\python.exe  # Interpreter
  : C:\\Python27\\include  # inc dir
  : C:\\Python27\\libs  # link libs
  : # conditions
  ;
```

And now get this, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450634/compile-boost-python-tutorial-with-vs-2015-ctp-5-and-python-3-5a-on-windows-10-t).

```
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
...found 7 targets...
    - symlinks supported       : yes
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
config-cache.write bin\project-cache.jam
...updated 1 target...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1916 targets...
...updating 5 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd
   Creating library bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb and object bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.exp
LINK : fatal error LNK1207: incompatible PDB format in 'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_60_0_64\libs\python\example\tutorial\bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb'; delete and rebuild

        call "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd" >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /NOENTRY /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd" /IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python27\libs"   @"bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd.rsp"
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pyd bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb...
...removing bin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi\hello_ext.pdb
...skipped <p.>hello_ext.pyd for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello_ext.pyd...
...skipped <pbin\hello.test\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello for lack of <pbin\msvc-14.0\debug\threading-multi>hello_ext.pyd...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 3 targets...
```

Comment: I ended up giving up on the boost-python library and learned the python C API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suffered similar problems as you and found this to be the main culprit:

```
    C:\Users\Joey\Anaconda2\libs\python27.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

You are mixing libraries of different bitness. When building 64-bit Boost Python you have to link to 64-bit Python and likewise for the 32-bit builds.

Make sure you install the two versions of Python to different directories. I used the default directory in the installers and both installations end up in the same directory. Even though I installed the 64-bit version after the 32-bit one, I still only had 32-bit libs in my Python libs/ folder.